# get a range of numbers from sql column of type varchar

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a postgres server running with one column (say `marks`)  of type `VARCHAR(255)`, but is supposed to have numbers, like if i do a `select *..` query , i will get `['100','50','21','14'...]` etc.
i would like to run a range query on it, like user passes `[10,30]` and gets `['21','14']` as result. I think this would require casting at the time of running the `BETWEEN` query, but i cannot get it to work properly.

I am using sequalize.js which is generating the following query:

```sql
SELECT "id"
FROM "token_attributes" AS "token_attributes"
WHERE "token_attributes"."attributesDirectoryId" = 3
  AND CAST('token_attributes.attributeValue' AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 10 AND 30;
```

on server also this query seems to fail. the sequalize query that is being created is :

```js
 {
  where: {
    attributesDirectoryId: 3,
    attributeValue: Where { attribute: [Cast], comparator: '=', logic: [Object] }
  },
  attributes: [ 'id' ]
}
```

i have used the following code to create the where condition (cast and where were imported from sequelize):

```js
let whereFilter ={}
 let value = where(cast(`${tableName}.attributeValue`, 'integer'), {[Op.between]: rangeAsInt})
whereFilter['attributeValue'] = value
```

so this is basically calling `table.findAll({where:whereFilter})` I am not sure how to either make sequelize create a correct sql api or what the actual correct SQL api would be. can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show some real recors from DB?

Comment: @Anatoly the records are just numbers like this. but since the column type is varchar, i showed them as string numbers. also, i just found the issue. so  thanks for considering this question :)

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, i missed the `sequilize.col` function :

```js
let whereFilter ={}
 let value = where(cast(col(`${tableName}.attributeValue`), 'integer'), {[Op.between]: rangeAsInt})
whereFilter['attributeValue'] = value
```

and the query would be :

```sql
SELECT "id"
FROM "token_attributes" AS "token_attributes"
WHERE "token_attributes"."attributesDirectoryId" = 3
  AND CAST("token_attributes"."attributeValue" AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 10 AND 30;
```